# I am getting different result with my excel Copy then Paste code

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a different RowNumber whenever I run my code.

```
Dim idRowCount As Long

idRowCount = Worksheets("MasterFile").Range("B:B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count  

Range("R2").Copy
Range("R3:R" & idRowCount).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

The total RowCount should be 325,000 but sometimes it only paste the formulas up to 180,000 or 150,000 cell row.

Is there anything wrong with my code or declaration?

I have already tried to paste the count value on a Range of cell and it gives the right number of constant value 325,000.
I also tried to temporarily replace the variable 'idRowCount' with the number 300,000 but it returns(paste) on different row number.

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to find the last row? Please see the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: Thanks for quick response @BigBen, but i left the lastRow looping formula for my project 'coz it takes time to load the procedure as it runs through each cell. Since i have constant worksheet formula, I decided to use the copy paste formula instead. But yeah, i'm getting this unknown return value. :(